# Symfony 3: FileType multiple and Many-to-Many database relation

Tags: php, file-upload, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

I got entity called **SupportMessage** which contains messages from my support (ticket) system. I want to implement feature which allows users and support agents attach files to their posts.

I also got an entity called **Files** where all files from my project are listed: file ID, file name, user and uploading date.

When user writes a message in my support system, he can attach multiple files. I think using `multiple=true` is more elegant way than creating CollectionType of FileType buttons, but I don't really know how to implement this feature and make it works. Didn't find any information in official docs and Google about this case.

When I send the form, I got an array of UploadedFile object, but not ArrayCollection, so everything fails:

> Expected value of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|array" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\SupportMessage#$attachments", got "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" instead.

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('ALLOWED_TO_VIEW_SUPPORT_TICKET', supportTicket)")
 * @Route("/support/ticket-{supportTicket}", name="view_ticket")
 *
 * @param Request       $request
 * @param SupportTicket $supportTicket
 * @return Response
 */
public function viewTicket(Request $request, SupportTicket $supportTicket)
{
    $translator  = $this->get('translator');
    $breadcrumbs = $this->get('white_october_breadcrumbs');

    $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem('app.name', 'homepage');
    $breadcrumbs->addRouteItem('page_title.support', 'my_support_tickets');
    $breadcrumbs->addItem($supportTicket->getTitle());

    $supportMessage = new SupportMessage();
    $supportMessage->setSupportTicket($supportTicket);
    $supportMessage->setUser($this->getUser());

    $form = $this->createForm(SupportMessageType::class, $supportMessage);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        foreach ($supportMessage->getAttachments() as $attachment) {
            $fileName = $this->get('app.file_uploader')->upload($attachment);

            $file = new File();
            $file->setFilename($fileName);
            $file->setUser($this->getUser());

            //$supportMessage->addAttachment($file);
        }

        //dump($supportMessage);die;

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($supportMessage);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', $translator->trans('support.flash_message.sent'));

        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
    }

    return $this->render('support/view-ticket.html.twig', [
        'title'         => $supportTicket->getTitle(),
        'supportTicket' => $supportTicket,
        'form'          => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Service:

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->targetDir, $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }
}
```

SupportMessage entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SupportMessage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=65535)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $message;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $postedAt;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $message
     */
    public function setMessage(?string $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getPostedAt()
    {
        return $this->postedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPostedAgo()
    {
        Carbon::setLocale('ru');

        return Carbon::instance($this->postedAt)->diffForHumans();
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $postedAt
     */
    public function setPostedAt($postedAt)
    {
        $this->postedAt = $postedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     *
     * @var User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SupportTicket", inversedBy="supportMessages")
     *
     * @var SupportTicket
     */
    private $supportTicket;

    /**
     * @return SupportTicket
     */
    public function getSupportTicket()
    {
        return $this->supportTicket;
    }

    /**
     * @param SupportTicket $supportTicket
     */
    public function setSupportTicket($supportTicket)
    {
        $this->supportTicket = $supportTicket;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="File", inversedBy="supportMessages")
     *
     * @var File[]
     */
    private $attachments;

    /**
     * @return File[]
     */
    public function getAttachments()
    {
        return $this->attachments;
    }

    /**
     * @param File[] $attachments
     */
    public function setAttachments($attachments)
    {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            $this->attachments->add($attachment);
        }

        //dump($this->attachments);die;
    }

    /**
     * @param File $attachment
     */
    public function addAttachment($attachment)
    {
        $this->attachments->add($attachment);
    }
}
```

File entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class File
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->uploadedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->supportMessages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @Assert\File
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     * @var User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $uploadedAt;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilename(): ?string
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $filename
     */
    public function setFilename(?string $filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUploadedAt()
    {
        return $this->uploadedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $uploadedAt
     */
    public function setUploadedAt($uploadedAt)
    {
        $this->uploadedAt = $uploadedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SupportMessage", mappedBy="attachments")
     *
     * @var Collection|SupportMessage[]
     */
    private $supportMessages;

    /**
     * @return Collection|SupportMessage[]
     */
    public function getSupportMessages()
    {
        return $this->supportMessages;
    }

    /**
     * @param Collection|SupportMessage[] $supportMessages
     */
    public function setSupportMessages($supportMessages)
    {
        $this->supportMessages = $supportMessages;
    }

    /**
     * @param SupportMessage $supportMessage
     */
    public function addSupportMessage($supportMessage)
    {
        $supportMessage->addAttachment($this);

        $this->supportMessages->add($supportMessage);
    }
}
```

Much thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please post both entities, and form class.

Comment: @michail_w, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my colleague found the problem. It was in my controller. I've attached `UploadedFile` objects there, but in the fact I needed to attach my entity `File` objects.

Fixed code snipped:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $attachments = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach ($supportMessage->getAttachments() as $attachment) {
        $fileName = $this->get('app.file_uploader')->upload($attachment);

        $file = new File();
        $file->setFilename($fileName);
        $file->setUser($this->getUser());

        $attachments->add($file);
        //$supportMessage->addAttachment($file);
    }

    $supportMessage->setAttachments($attachments);

    // ... other code here ...
}
```